# Reordering li elements for jQuery "sortable" problem

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, html-lists

I have built a sortable list using jQuery UI's sortable feature, this is working fine except that I need to be able to reorder the `<li>` at the beginning depending upon a string containing the element's order but I cannot figure out the syntax how to do this with JavaScript.

Lets say I have the following:

```
<ul>
   <li id="A" >Apple</li>
   <li id="B" >Banana</li>
   <li id="C" >Carrot</li>
</ul>
```

and the string "C,A,B"

I would like to have a JavaScript function for reordering my the items inside the  which bases the ordering off of the order of the string. Ending up with this:

```
 <ul>
   <li id="C" >Carrot</li>
   <li id="A" >Apple</li>
   <li id="B" >Banana</li>
</ul>
```

I will be naturally splitting the string back out by its "," and ending up with an array of element Id's, but I am unsure of two main things in this.

1) What is the best way to get the element which the specified Id found in my split string array?

2) Once I have gotten that element and determined it is the correct element, what is the syntax for or best strategy for placing them in the proper order?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should answer both (1) and (2).

You can split the string on the `,` delimiter to get an array, and then just loop through changing the order of the `li` elements.

```
var order = 'C,A,B'.split(','),
    ul = $('ul');

$.each(order, function(index, sort) {
    $('#' + sort).appendTo(ul);
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/2TqBn/).

Comment: Perfect, don't know why I was having so much trouble coming up with the right code on that!   Thank you for the quick response!

Comment: @BVSmallman No worries, thanks for being a perfect example of a good Stack Overflow citizen :)